# Why I get error when I try to use value defined in web config?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I work on MVC5 project.

In my web config I have this key value:

```
<add key="WebLayoutPath" value="../../data/reuno/?WEBLAYOUT={0}" />
```

I want to use the key  value above in iframe element that inside cshtml,view page.

So I change this:

```
<div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="mgArea">
   <iframe id="iframeMgMap" 
           src="@(string.Format("../../data/reuno/?WEBLAYOUT={0}",Model.MgPath))"
           frameborder="0"
           scrolling="no"
           style="width:100%;height:100%;"></iframe>
</div>
```

to this:

```
<div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="mgArea">
    <iframe id="iframeMgMap"     
            src="@(string.Format(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["WebLayoutPath"],Model.MgPath))"
            frameborder="0"
            scrolling="no"
            style="width:100%;height:100%;"></iframe>
</div>
```

But when I make changes above I get this error:

```
"Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: format"
```

I think the the problem with the syntex os the src attribute.

Any idea how to fix the problem?

Comment: The key is "WebLayoutPath" not "logoPath". Also I would move this to your model and not access it directly in the view.

Comment: I updated code!

Answer (score 1):

You can consider passing that down to the view from the action itself in the `ViewBag`

```
//...
var format = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["WebLayoutPath"];
var path = string.Format(format, model.MgPath);
ViewBag.MgPath = path;

return View(model);
```

and access it in the View

```
<div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="mgArea">
   <iframe id="iframeMgMap" 
           src="@((string)ViewBag.MgPath)"
           frameborder="0"
           scrolling="no"
           style="width:100%;height:100%;"></iframe>
</div>
```